# Add env variable to index.html src and got error "Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node."

Tags: reactjs, webpack, .env

In my React webpack project I added env variable (VERSION) into my index.html. It works!

**webpack.config.js**

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin from "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin";
import CompressionPlugin from "compression-webpack-plugin";
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
import webpack from "webpack";
import path from "path";
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from "html-webpack-plugin";

dotenv.config();

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve("src/index.tsx"),
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
      },

      {
        test: /\.less|css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "style-loader",
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
          },
          {
            loader: "less-loader",
            options: {
              lessOptions: {
                modifyVars: {
                  "@primary-color": "#009ef7",
                  "@height-base": "40px",
                  "@height-lg": "45px",
                  "@border-radius-base": "5px",
                  "@text-color-secondary": "rgba(0,0,0,.3)",
                  "@radio-size": "20px",
                  "@input-bg": "#ffffff",
                  "@input-border-color": "#D9DBE4",
                  "@label-color": "#a1a5b7",
                  "@btn-default-bg": "#E4E6EF",
                  "@btn-default-color": "#7E8299",
                  "@btn-default-border": "#F5F8FA",
                  "@btn-primary-bg": "#3E97FF",
                  "@btn-primary-border": "#3E97FF",
                  "@input-hover-border-color": "#B5B5C3",
                  "@checkbox-size": "20px",

                  "@input-height-lg": "43px",

                  "@btn-font-weight": "500",
                  "@menu-item-color": "#A1A5B7",
                },
                javascriptEnabled: true,
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/i,
        issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
        use: ["@svgr/webpack"],
      },
      {
        test: /\\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg|gif)$/,
        use: ["file-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
      path.resolve(__dirname, "."),
      "node_modules",
    ],
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
  
  },
  mode: "development",
  plugins: [
    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": JSON.stringify(process.env),
    }),
    new CompressionPlugin({
      algorithm: "gzip",
      test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8,
    }),
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-escape
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /(en)$/),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "public/index.html",
      filename: "index.html",
      templateParameters: {
        VERSION: process.env.VERSION,
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

**index body**

```
 <body>
    <div id="root">
     ...
    <script src="bundle.js?v=<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.templateParameters.VERSION %>"></script>
  </body>
```

**.env file**

```
VERSION=version1
```

This is all I changed. And now I got this:

[image]

Don't know what to do, I have no "removeChild" methods in my project at all. What's wrong?

search for "removeChild" methods in project. Google the error. Ask ChatGPT